# This returns nothing. Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, where-clause

```
SELECT 
    Recipes.RecipeID, Recipes.RecipeTitle
FROM 
    Recipes 
INNER JOIN
    Recipe_Ingredients ON Recipes.RecipeID = Recipe_Ingredients.RecipeID 
INNER JOIN
    Ingredients ON Ingredients.IngredientID = Recipe_Ingredients.IngredientID
WHERE 
   (Ingredients.IngredientName = 'Beef') 
   AND (Ingredients.IngredientName = 'Garlic')
```

This SQL query returns nothing. However when I checked the where conditions individually/ separately without putting them together with AND, they come up with a recipe called "Roast Beef" that actually has both beef and garlic. Hence, shouldn't it show up as 1 row in the result. But it doesn't show anything. Why?

Comment: Please try below
SELECT Recipes.RecipeID, Recipes.RecipeTitle FROM Recipes INNER JOIN Recipe_Ingredients ON Recipes.RecipeID = Recipe_Ingredients.RecipeID INNER JOIN Ingredients ON Ingredients.IngredientID = Recipe_Ingredients.IngredientID WHERE Ingredients.IngredientName = 'Beef' and Ingredients.IngredientName = 'Garlic'

Comment: An ingredient name cannot possibly be *Beef* AND *Garlic* at the same time. What does AND mean when you use it in a sentence?

Comment: Replace `and` with `or` in your `where` clause

Answer (score 4):

It is returning `NULL`, because an ingredient cannot have to names at the same time.  You would seem to want:

```
SELECT r.RecipeID, r.RecipeTitle
FROM Recipes r INNER JOIN
     Recipe_Ingredients ri
     ON r.RecipeID = ri.RecipeID INNER JOIN
     Ingredients i
     ON i.IngredientID = ri.IngredientID
WHERE i.IngredientName IN ('Beef', 'Garlic')
GROUP BY r.RecipeID, r.RecipeTitle
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.IngredientName) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

AND operates at row level. The IngredientName can't be both 'Beef' and 'Garlic' at the same time for the same row. You may have to join with Ingredients again.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use AND operator for multi condition in same column, if you want to select 2 condition for same column use IN operator.

```
SELECT Recipes.RecipeID, Recipes.RecipeTitle
FROM Recipes INNER JOIN
Recipe_Ingredients ON Recipes.RecipeID = Recipe_Ingredients.RecipeID 
INNER JOIN
Ingredients ON Ingredients.IngredientID = Recipe_Ingredients.IngredientID
WHERE (Ingredients.IngredientName in ('Beef' , 'Garlic') )
```